Identify this game piece
Found this on the floor, cannot figure out which board game it fell from, I have too many!!!
Please help!

The picture depicts reddish/brownish token with 8 corners and somewhat curved sides. At the top "4th" is printed in black. There is a pictogram of a white building under the text.
